# Android: Recyclerview onClick(int position) adding to previous position upon refresh

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

As noob developer im developing a flashcards app where i am populating cards using recyclerview. The issue is when i add a new card using a FAB, i refresh Main activity. Here i find that when i click on any card it doesnt display any data. Debugging revealed that the position of onClick(int position) in the recyclerview fragment adds on the previous size of the cards and thus im unable to see the data. How to get correct onClick position? Please help..

```
public class CardFragment extends Fragment {
public static List<String> QArray = new ArrayList<>();
public CardFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final OnSelectFlashListner mCallback = null;

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final RecyclerView flashRecycler = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.recy_view , container, false);

    try{
        SQLiteOpenHelper flashCardsHelper1 = new FlashCardsHelper(getContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = flashCardsHelper1.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query("Flashdata",new String[]{"question", "answer"},null,null,null,null,null);
        Log.d("Flash data", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                QArray.add(cursor.getString(0));
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    flashAdapter flashAdap = new flashAdapter(QArray);
    flashRecycler.setAdapter(flashAdap);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    flashRecycler.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    flashAdap.setListner(new flashAdapter.Listner(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(int position) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),FlashCardOpen.class);
            intent.putExtra(FlashCardOpen.EXXTRA_QUESTIONNO,position);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    Button button = (Button)flashRecycler.findViewById(R.id.btn_Add);

    return flashRecycler;
}
```

im refreshing the Main activity via FAB:

```
private void loadFAB() {
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_box);
            dialog.setTitle("Add Flash Card");

            final EditText textViewQues = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.et_dialogQuestion);
            final EditText textViewAns = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.et_dialogAnswer);
            Button btn_cancel = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
            btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            Button btn_add = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_Add);
            btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    writeToDb(textViewQues.getText().toString(),textViewAns.getText().toString());
                    showNotif();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, this was not the problem at all. I was populating an array list which kept on appending the whole list on top of previous one. i simply added the array.clear() at start of view onCreateView() and the problem was resolved.
Debugging rules!